# ansible inventory に、他の group の内容を指定したい

Tags: ansible

ansible の inventory の設定で、たまたま、同じ host を指定できる場合があったとします。
(すべてのサーバーを1筐体に入れたい場合など、よくこれが起こると思います。)

その場合に、あるグループで指定したホストの内容を、そのまま他のグループに指定したい場合があります。

これを実現する方法はありますか？

というのも、同じIPを別のグループに、ひたすらべた書きしていくと、後々取り回しが効きにくいと考えるからです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[groups-of-groups](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#groups-of-groups-and-group-variables)という機能があって、`[groupname:children]`で他のgroupのhostを加ることができます。

例としてinventoryは以下の様に

```
[group1]
host1
host2

[group2]
host3
host4

[group3:children]
group1
group2
```

`ansible --list-hosts group3` は正しくhost1-4を表示します。